# How to populate a Listbox in C++ with all folders in a directory

Tags: c++, listbox, openfiledialog

I would like to know how to list all folder in a directory in a listbox. I am using Visual C++.

Comment: Hello Kuzon.  Welcome to StackOverflow...and beware, as not everyone on the Internet is going to click through to see your age, and may downvote and/or gripe at you for writing too short a question.  :-/  Please note that you should not sign your questions/answers...(and read through the rest of the FAQ as well)... http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is a language that does not specify any standard classes or functions for implementing graphical interfaces.  It also doesn't provide a standard way of getting lists of files and directories from the operating system!!!  In fact...for a long time there wasn't even a standard for string classes, and every project chose different incompatible strings.

*Note: Even though there's now a standard `string` class, the fragmented legacy continues: [Why is there a different string class in every C++ platform out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618798/why-is-there-a-different-string-class-in-every-c-platform-out-there)*

So when you tag something "C++" or use that term, it refers only the language engine itself.  As limited as that may sound, one of the great strengths is that this engine is so (relatively) powerful that you don't *need* to build things in to make them efficient or have a deep coding interface.  Users of the language have nearly as much power to create cool language features as if they were able to modify the compiler itself.

It's a steep hill to climb for beginners, though.

---

All of that means that a question like *"How to populate a Listbox in C++ with all folders in a directory?"* is very open-ended.  It depends on what toolkits you're choosing to use for the GUI, and for talking to the filesystem.  Some toolkits are "big" and offer comprehensive classes to cover both areas:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdir.html#navigation-and-directory-operations

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/itemviews-dirview.html

Other libraries are more narrow and provide just one function or another.  For instance, "boost" is a set of *almost* standard libraries that haven't yet made it into the C++ spec.  There's a way to enumerate files and directories with C++ using `boost::filesystem`.  It's daunting for beginners, though:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html

If you're willing to chain yourself to a particular operating system or implementation--such as make calls to functions only available on Windows, or only on Linux under GTK, or only on MacOS--then you have access to what that platform+toolkit provides.  But because C++ is platform-independent, once you cross that line you're no longer programming in "just C++" and your question and tags on StackOverflow need to clarify what choices you've made.

Your other questions on SO are about Visual Studio and VB so I'm assuming you're using Windows.

---

One related topic you should be aware of are "common dialogs".  These are conveniences provided so that everyone doesn't have to write their own "File->Open" logic, or color picker, or search dialog.  Microsoft has some of them defined on Windows:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646960(v=VS.85).aspx

So if picking a file, files, directory, or directories is the simple purpose of some code...those save you the trouble.  Qt has similar things:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qfiledialog.html#details

---

You can edit your question to add more about your purposes.  If you are curious about C++ and just want to dive in and have a well-documented set of functionality that will work on Windows, Mac, or Linux... consider trying Qt Creator:

http://www.qt.io/ide/

Microsoft has really hinged their strategy on .NET and C#, so at least right now you'll stand on firmer ground as a C++ GUI programmer if you go with Qt.

Comment: Thanks, Wow. This is so much more complex then I am used to. I have only really worked on visual basics and this is a very big step by the look of things...

Comment: I think I will look into Qt... I am just trying to learn as I go along. They don't offer this sort of thing in grade 9 at my school

Comment: For several years, Qt has been my favorite C++ UI framework.  I will point out that as it uses C++, it's going to still have a somewhat steep learning curve relative to other languages.  If you are trying to learn the principles of C++ with pointers/references and other things, I'd really suggest sticking to some basic textual input/output exercises first; that gives you a much better shot at understanding the principles of using Qt (or any C++ UI framework) properly.

Comment: While it's a little advanced, there's something in Qt that is very useful called QFileSystemModel.  A lot of old "widget" toolkits made graphical objects store the data...so if you had a list box on the screen with 100 items then all 100 items would need to be added and stored "inside" the list box.  If you had another way of "viewing" that data you would again add 100 items to it.  Qt separates the data model from the view, you can read about that.  Perhaps you'll then get why QFileSystemModel is cool:  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative one, free and open-source, called Nana C++ Library(http://stdex.sourceforge.net), a pure C++ GUI library.

[There is a tutorial to populate a treebox with folders.](http://stdex.sourceforge.net/help/gui/treebox.htm)

The status of the library is active, and it is updated monthly. This is a new library, it would be a choice for your hobby project.